# Need to regex substitute "[ABC123]" to lowercase minus braces?

Tags: regex

Using pac4j/knox identity assertion Regex to convert incoming identity to lowercase id. I am assuming it is using Java regex hence trying to convert certain identity fields to correct format. But due to lack of documentation cant figure out what regex will work to get desired output. ref. [knox identity assertion regex](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/configuring-proxy-knox/content/regular_expression_identity_assertion_provider.html)

output can be passed by {1} etc by group backreference.

Was able to extract group1 by using below:
expression : [(.*?)]
Input: [ABC123]
output: ABC123
[image]
But cannot seem to convert to lowercase using \L.

Can any fellow peep help with alternate approach (if any)??

Comment: In Java, regex replacement does not support case changing operators.

Comment: Trying an alternate approach to use lookup to substitute Uppercase alphabets with lowercase counterparts. Exp I am trying: `\[([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])(\d{3})\]` which is able to catch 6 groups. However I want it dynamic since input string can be 2-5 letter followed by 3 digits. It would only capture groups if length matches with declaration. Any suggestion ?

[ABC123] or [AB123] not working. exactly a 5 char length [ABCDE123] is working.

Comment: You can make groups optional with `?`, e.g. `\[([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])?([A-Z])?([A-Z])?(\d{3})\]`. However, the replacement pattern will also need to be "conditional". This is not supported by many engines, Boost does, as in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wictor was able to find a workaround with group replacement using "Lookup" dictionary containing Uppercase > lowercase conversion.

```
role=identity-assertion
identity-assertion.name=Regex
identity-assertion.enabled=true
identity-assertion.param.input=\[([A-Z])([A-Z])([A-Z])?([A-Z])?([A-Z])?(\d{3})\]
identity-assertion.param.output={[1]}{[2]}{[3]}{[4]}{[5]}{6}
identity-assertion.param.lookup=A=a;B=b;C=c;D=d;E=e;F=f;G=g;H=h;I=i;J=j;K=k;L=l;M=m;N=n;O=o;P=p;Q=q;R=r;S=s;T=t;U=u;V=v;W=w;X=x;Y=y;Z=z
```